How can I optimize the performance of this regex pattern that extracts messages in python?
I need a regex pattern to create a Pandas DataFrame with three separate columns: date, user, and message. I believe regex is the best option for this case, but if there are other methods that can achieve the same result more quickly, I would like to know.
The pattern must:

Capture whole messages, including multiline messages.

Detect when there is no user and classify it as a group notification in the user column.


I already created one, but I feel like it isn't really optimized, and it takes several seconds to run on large datasets. Here’s the pattern I currently have, along with an example of the data and the format I need to extract.
data = """
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with multiple lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User3: Hi StackOverflow
"""


pattern = r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s-\s'

#pass the pattern and data to split it to get the list of messages with users
messages = re.split(pattern, data)[1:]

#extract all dates
dates = re.findall(pattern, data)

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_message': messages, 'date': dates})

#separate Users and Message
users = []
messages = []
for message in df['user_message']:
    entry = re.split(r'([\w\W]+?):\s', message)
    if entry[1:]:  # user name
        users.append(entry[1])
        messages.append(" ".join(entry[2:]))
    else:
        users.append('group_notification')
        messages.append(entry[0])

df['user'] = users
df['message'] = messages
df.drop(columns=['user_message'], inplace=True)


can usernames or messages contain each of the following characters "/:-"

Regexp are flexible but generally pretty slow. If you work on ASCII strings, then you can do your own parsing in a native compiled language, this will likely be 10x to 100x faster (regarding the level of optimization of the native code).

If you really want to use regexp for flexibility, then you can play a bit with the engine so to reduce backtracks. This requires some example strings slow to parse in average (not provided) and the actual regexp. An alternative is to use a regexp engine that is guaranteed to take a linear time but I do not think this is a problem here.

A naive alternative way is to use multiple process to do the regexp computation since regexp code is generally compute bound (otherwise it can make it slower).

If users can write multi-line messages, they can insert lines that look like they are from someone else. How do you deal with that?

Given the sample data in your question, what would you want the dataframe to look like? Also, what is the date format? Your sample data is ambiguous.

@SIGHUP The main goal is to separate the date, users, and messages into different columns, just like the code I provided does with the example. I will handle the date format later by converting the date column to datetime and managing different date format scenarios

@JonSG Sorry for not clarifying that, yes, they can

@ken I'm afraid I can't, maybe the added text would just appear as another user or conversation.

What are the rules for usernames (for length, first character, other characters, ...etc)? Is there a closed set of words a group message can start with ("Group", "Admin", ...)? Can group messages have a colon (":")? If so, what is the discriminating factor between these two types of messages?

@trincot There isn't any specific rule for usernames. There isn't a closed set of words that a group message can start with (well, there is, but it involves usernames like "Dylan changed the group name," but I can’t know usernames in advance). Group messages don’t have a colon unless a username includes one; if that’s the case, there could be confusion (I don’t see an easy way to avoid that, so it might be dispensable).

Ok then it is just not possible.

@trincot what if we asume there is no colon in group notifications?

Assuming that a user cannot mess about and construct a multi-line message that mimics a new entry, I would probably parse this manually rather than using regex and then load the data into pandas if you really needed that.
The trick here is to maintain a handle on a "prior" record so that in the event that we have a continued message we can extend the prior message.
Here is a concept you can play with:
import io
import datetime
import pandas

FILE_TEXT = """
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with multiple lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User 3: Hi : StackOverflow
"""

def try_parse_date(date_string):
    potential_formats = [
        "%m/%d/%y, %H:%M",
        "%d/%m/%y, %H:%M"
    ]

    final_error = None
    for potential_format in potential_formats:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, potential_format)
        except ValueError as e:
            final_error = e
    raise final_error

results = []
prior = {}
with io.StringIO(FILE_TEXT) as file_in:
    for index, row in enumerate(file_in):
        row = row.strip()
        if not row:
            continue

        ## ------------------------
        ## We have a row, break it in to potential parts
        ## ------------------------
        potential_date, *potential_user_and_message = row.rstrip("\n").split(" - ")
        potential_user_and_message = " - ".join(potential_user_and_message)
        ## ------------------------

        ## ------------------------
        ## If this row does not start with a date
        ## assume it is part of the prior message
        ## ------------------------
        try:
            best_date_guess = try_parse_date(potential_date)
        except ValueError:
            if not index:
                raise ValueError(f"The first row must start with a valid date")
            print(f"**Warning** row {index} does not begin with valid date")
            prior["message"] += row
            continue
        ## ------------------------

        ## ------------------------
        ## Break the remaining text into user and message
        ## ------------------------
        potential_user, *potential_message = potential_user_and_message.split(":")
        if potential_message:
            best_user_guess = potential_user
            best_message_guess = ":".join(potential_message)
        else:
            best_user_guess = "group_notification"
            best_message_guess = potential_user_and_message
        ## ------------------------

        ## ------------------------
        ## The prior record is complete
        ## ------------------------
        if prior:
            results.append(prior)
        ## ------------------------

        ## ------------------------
        ## Reset the prior record to this record
        ## ------------------------
        prior = {"date": best_date_guess, "user": best_user_guess, "message": best_message_guess}
        ## ------------------------

    ## ------------------------
    ## The prior record is complete
    ## ------------------------
    if prior:
        results.append(prior)
    ## ------------------------

print(pandas.DataFrame(results))

That should give you:
                 date                user                                         message
0 2022-09-06 11:28:00  group_notification           Group creator created group "Example"
1 2022-09-06 11:39:00               User1                               This is some text
2 2022-09-06 11:58:00  group_notification  Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
3 2022-09-06 12:13:00               User2             This issome textwith multiple lines
4 2022-09-06 13:13:00  group_notification               Admin changed group profile photo
5 2022-09-06 14:45:00              User 3                              Hi : StackOverflow


This works well, but if the username contains any blank spaces (I didn’t clarify that; I’m sorry), like "User 3" here, it is classified as a group notification:  data = """
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group
"Example"
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with multiple lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User 3: Hi StackOverflow
""".strip()

If the username can contain a space, then you have to split on :, however that introduces a problem where a group message must never include such a character. Seems to me that at this point perhaps going back to the source of the data and unsuring that it is properly deliminated and escaped might be in order.

I noticed another problem, this restricts the date format to only one, what if I want to try three different date formats? I can´t catch the ValueError and try another format in a list of formats because that would interfere with multiline messages in this line "prior["message"] += row ". I tried dateutil.parser.parse(parts[0]) but it´s too slow

you can technically nest the try blocks and have only the final, inner most excpt do the prior/continue

This is a similar approach to JonSG, but uses pandas from the start.
import pandas as pd

def pandas_solution(data: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"line": data.splitlines(keepends=True)})

    # Parse date.
    # Assuming that multi-line messages have no line with a date prefix.
    df[["date", "body"]] = df["line"].str.split(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y, %H:%M", errors="coerce")

    # If the line has no date, it must be a multi-line message.
    # If it is a multi-line message, merge it into the last line with a date prefix.
    is_multiline_message = df["date"].isna()
    df["message_index"] = (~is_multiline_message).cumsum()
    df.loc[is_multiline_message, "body"] = df.loc[is_multiline_message, "line"]
    df = df.groupby("message_index").agg({"date": "first", "body": "sum"})

    # Parse user and message.
    # Assuming that group notifications have no colon.
    df[["user", "message"]] = df["body"].str.split(": ", n=1, expand=True)
    is_group_notification = df["message"].isna()
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "message"] = df.loc[is_group_notification, "user"]
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "user"] = "group_notification"
    df.drop("body", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

Benchmark:
import datetime
import io
import re
import timeit

import pandas as pd

pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 300)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)


def baseline(data):
    pattern = r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s-\s'

    # pass the pattern and data to split it to get the list of messages with users
    messages = re.split(pattern, data)[1:]

    # extract all dates
    dates = re.findall(pattern, data)

    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'user_message': messages, 'date': dates})

    # separate Users and Message
    users = []
    messages = []
    for message in df['user_message']:
        entry = re.split(r'([\w\W]+?):\s', message)
        if entry[1:]:  # user name
            users.append(entry[1])
            messages.append(" ".join(entry[2:]))
        else:
            users.append('group_notification')
            messages.append(entry[0])

    df['user'] = users
    df['message'] = messages
    df.drop(columns=['user_message'], inplace=True)
    return df


def jon_solution(data: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    results = []
    prior = {}
    with io.StringIO(data) as file_in:
        for row in file_in:
            parts = row.split(" - ")

            ## ------------------------
            ## If this row does not start with a date
            ## assume it is part of the prior message
            ## ------------------------
            try:
                current = {
                    "date": datetime.datetime.strptime(parts[0], "%m/%d/%y, %H:%M"),
                    "user": "group_notification",
                    "message": ""
                }
            except ValueError:
                prior["message"] += row
                continue
            ## ------------------------

            ## ------------------------
            ## The prior record is complete
            ## ------------------------
            if prior:
                results.append(prior)
            ## ------------------------

            ## ------------------------
            ## Break the remaining text into user and message
            ## ------------------------
            sub_parts = parts[1].split(":")
            if len(sub_parts) > 1:
                current["user"] = sub_parts[0]
                current["message"] = ":".join(sub_parts[1:])
            else:
                current["message"] = parts[1]
            ## ------------------------

            prior = current

        ## ------------------------
        ## The prior record is complete
        ## ------------------------
        results.append(prior)
        ## ------------------------

    return pd.DataFrame(results)


def pandas_solution(data: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"line": data.splitlines(keepends=True)})

    # Parse date.
    # Assuming that multi-line messages have no line with a date prefix.
    df[["date", "body"]] = df["line"].str.split(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y, %H:%M", errors="coerce")

    # If the line has no date, it must be a multi-line message.
    # If it is a multi-line message, merge it into the last line with a date prefix.
    is_multiline_message = df["date"].isna()
    df["message_index"] = (~is_multiline_message).cumsum()
    df.loc[is_multiline_message, "body"] = df.loc[is_multiline_message, "line"]
    df = df.groupby("message_index").agg({"date": "first", "body": "sum"}).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse user and message.
    # Assuming that group notifications have no colon.
    df[["user", "message"]] = df["body"].str.split(": ", n=1, expand=True)
    is_group_notification = df["message"].isna()
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "message"] = df.loc[is_group_notification, "user"]
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "user"] = "group_notification"
    df.drop("body", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df


def benchmark():
    data = """\
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with - multiple: lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User3: Hi StackOverflow
"""
    data *= 100000

    for f in [baseline, jon_solution, pandas_solution]:
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: f(data), number=1, repeat=3)
        print(f"{f.__name__}: {min(t)}")


benchmark()

Result:
baseline: 7.355876599998737
jon_solution: 5.135336500003177
pandas_solution: 1.501740499999869

I haven't tested it, but polars is probably faster, and it might be even faster if we can use numba.

This is quite elegant, although I found that JonSG's solution is much faster if you use regex. Maybe yours could be faster if I manage to implement Polars or Numba.

I noticed that the bottleneck in JonSG's solution was in the strptime part, so I used regex instead, and it turns out it's even faster than the pandas solution.
import io
import pandas as pd
import re

def jon_regex(data:str) -> pd.DataFrame:
results = []
prior = {}
date_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}, \d{1,2}:\d{2}$')

with io.StringIO(data.strip()) as file_in:
    for row in file_in:
        parts = row.split(" - ")

        ## ------------------------
        ## If this row does not start with a date
        ## assume it is part of the prior message
        ## ------------------------
        found_date = False
        # Check if date
        check = bool(date_pattern.match(parts[0]))
        if check:
            current = {
                "date": parts[0],
                "user": "group_notification",
                "message": ""
            }
            found_date = True

        if not found_date:
            if prior:
                prior["message"] += " " + row.strip()
            continue  # Pasar a la siguiente fila

        ## ------------------------
        ## The prior record is complete
        ## ------------------------
        if prior:
            results.append(prior)

        ## ------------------------
        ## Break the remaining text into user and message
        ## ------------------------
        sub_parts = parts[1].split(":")
        if len(sub_parts) > 1:
            current["user"] = sub_parts[0].strip()
            current["message"] = ":".join(sub_parts[1:]).strip()
        else:
            current["message"] = parts[1].strip()

        prior = current

    # ------------------------
    # The prior record is complete
    # ------------------------
    if prior:
        results.append(prior)

    # Create Dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)

    #Change to datetime if needed
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m/%d/%y, %H:%M')
    
    return df

Benchmark:
import io
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime
import timeit
def jon_solution(data: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    results = []
    prior = {}
    with io.StringIO(data) as file_in:
        for row in file_in:
            parts = row.split(" - ")

            ## ------------------------
            ## If this row does not start with a date
            ## assume it is part of the prior message
            ## ------------------------
            try:
                current = {
                    "date": datetime.datetime.strptime(
                        parts[0], "%m/%d/%y, %H:%M"),
                    "user": "group_notification",
                    "message": ""
                }
            except ValueError:
                prior["message"] += row
                continue
            ## ------------------------

            ## ------------------------
            ## The prior record is complete
            ## ------------------------
            if prior:
                results.append(prior)
            ## ------------------------

            ## ------------------------
            ## Break the remaining text into user and message
            ## ------------------------
            sub_parts = parts[1].split(":")
            if len(sub_parts) > 1:
                current["user"] = sub_parts[0]
                current["message"] = ":".join(sub_parts[1:])
            else:
                current["message"] = parts[1]
            ## ------------------------

            prior = current

        ## ------------------------
        ## The prior record is complete
        ## ------------------------
        results.append(prior)
        ## ------------------------

    return pd.DataFrame(results)


def pandas_solution(data: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"line": data.splitlines(keepends=True)})

    # Parse date.
    # Assuming that multi-line messages have no line with a date prefix.
    df[["date", "body"]] = df["line"].str.split(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(
        df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y, %H:%M", errors="coerce")

    # If the line has no date, it must be a multi-line message.
    # If it is a multi-line message, merge it into the last line with a date prefix.
    is_multiline_message = df["date"].isna()
    df["message_index"] = (~is_multiline_message).cumsum()
    df.loc[is_multiline_message, "body"] = df.loc[is_multiline_message, "line"]
    df = df.groupby("message_index").agg(
        {"date": "first", "body": "sum"}).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse user and message.
    # Assuming that group notifications have no colon.
    df[["user", "message"]] = df["body"].str.split(": ", n=1, expand=True)
    is_group_notification = df["message"].isna()
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "message"] = df.loc[
        is_group_notification, "user"]
    df.loc[is_group_notification, "user"] = "group_notification"
    df.drop("body", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

def jon_regex(data:str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    results = []
    prior = {}
    date_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}, \d{1,2}:\d{2}$')

    with io.StringIO(data.strip()) as file_in:
        for row in file_in:
            parts = row.split(" - ")

            ## ------------------------
            ## If this row does not start with a date
            ## assume it is part of the prior message
            ## ------------------------
            found_date = False
            # Check if date
            check = bool(date_pattern.match(parts[0]))
            if check:
                current = {
                    "date": parts[0],
                    "user": "group_notification",
                    "message": ""
                }
                found_date = True

            if not found_date:
                if prior:
                    prior["message"] += " " + row.strip()
                continue  # Pasar a la siguiente fila

            ## ------------------------
            ## The prior record is complete
            ## ------------------------
            if prior:
                results.append(prior)

            ## ------------------------
            ## Break the remaining text into user and message
            ## ------------------------
            sub_parts = parts[1].split(":")
            if len(sub_parts) > 1:
                current["user"] = sub_parts[0].strip()
                current["message"] = ":".join(sub_parts[1:]).strip()
            else:
                current["message"] = parts[1].strip()

            prior = current

        # ------------------------
        # The prior record is complete
        # ------------------------
        if prior:
            results.append(prior)

        # Create Dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(results)

        #Change to datetime if needed
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m/%d/%y, %H:%M')
        
        return df

def benchmark():
    data = """\
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group "Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with multiple lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User 3: Hi StackOverflow
"""
    data *= 100000

    for f in [jon_solution, pandas_solution,jon_regex]:
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: f(data), number=1, repeat=3)
        print(f"{f.__name__}: {min(t)}")


benchmark()

Result:
jon_solution: 4.189222200075164
pandas_solution: 1.2554905998986214
jon_regex: 0.977813399862498


I wonder how much of "my" overhead is parsing and how much is creating the datetime object. Nice work in any case.

@JonSG Well, using pyinstrument as a profiler we can see that it is around 75%:                   100.0% wrapper  legend.py:26
└─ 99.7% jon_solution  legend.py:61
├─ 76.7% datetime._strptime_datetime  _strptime.py:551
│  ├─ 70.3% _strptime  _strptime.py:293
│  │  ├─ 35.3% [self]  _strptime.py
│  │  ├─ 20.4% _getlang  _strptime.py:26
│  │  │  ├─ 18.3% getlocale  locale.py:582
│  │  │  │  ├─ 8.7% _parse_localename  locale.py:464 (It’s just a part of the profiler output; it doesn’t fit entirely here)

A simpler regex to capture date and user_message and then post-processes it to separate users and messages will  slow down execution for large datasets.

pattern = r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s-\s(.*)'

matches = re.findall(pattern, data)
df = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['date', 'user_message'])
users = []
messages = []
for message in df['user_message']:
    entry = re.split(r'([^:]+):\s', message, maxsplit=1)
    if len(entry) > 2:  # user and message found
        users.append(entry[1])
        messages.append(entry[2].strip())
    else:
        users.append('group_notification')      messages.append(entry[0].strip())

df['user'] = users
df['message'] = messages
df.drop(columns=['user_message'], inplace=True)


This will output as :
              date                user                                            message
0  9/6/22, 11:28  group_notification               Group creator created group "Example"
1  9/6/22, 11:39               User1                                 This is some text
2  9/6/22, 11:58  group_notification  Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
3  9/6/22, 12:13               User2  This is\nsome text\nwith multiple lines
4  9/6/22, 13:13  group_notification               Admin changed group profile photo
5  9/6/22, 14:45               User3                              Hi StackOverflow


This seems to work pretty well and quickly. However, if there is a multiline group notification message, like in the following data:  data = """
9/6/22, 11:28 - Group creator created group
"Example"
9/6/22, 11:39 - User1: This is some text
9/6/22, 11:58 - Group creator changed group name to "Example2"
9/6/22, 12:13 - User2: This is
some text
with multiple lines
9/6/22, 13:13 - Admin changed group profile photo
9/6/22, 14:45 - User3: Hi StackOverflow
""" all messages get shifted.
